# How to access pixels inside contour region and write back to the original image using opencv in android

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, contour

I have written some code which will return contours from the actual image. I would like to access each contour, do some image manipulation at pixel level and write back to the image.

Is there a way to access the region of contour individually and iterate over individual pixel in the region and write back to the image.

```
      Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(matOfPoint);
      Mat roiBox = rgbaMatrix.submat(rect)
```

This returns a sub matrix which also has the pixels which are not part of the contour.

[Please follow this link to see the screenshot of contour detections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGUXI.jpg)

Comment: I think the easy way is to create a mask by drawing your contours as filled white polygons on a new black image.

Answer (score 2):

I found of a way which will always hold the context of the main matrix, as @AlexanderReynolds suggested masking is the only way to extract the exact region.

```
Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(matOfPoint);
Mat subMat = new Mat(mRgba,rect);
Mat zeroMat = Mat.zeros(subMat.size(),subMat.type());
zeroMat.copyTo(subMat);
```

This copies the zero matrix to the original matrix